# Angularjs ui grid dynamic cell template value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In angularjs ui grid, I have the cell template as shown below :

`cellTemplate: " <div class="progress"> <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 20%"></div> </div>"`

Now I need to dynamically set width percentage( `style="width: 20%"`) based on cell value, it could be `30% or 40% or 53%, etc`. How can we make it dynamic using `row.entity.status`? status is my column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provide very useful directive called ng-style

```
ng-style="{width:'{{dynamicValue}}%'}"
```

In this case

```
cellTemplate: ' <div class="progress"> <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-style="{width:'{{dynamicValue}}%'}"></div> </div>'
```

Comment: Rishabh, do you have any answer for a similar question with ng-class. Please find my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170055/ui-cell-template-needs-dynamic-ng-style/40170178#40170178