# ui cell template needs dynamic ng style

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

In angularjs ui grid, I have the cell template as shown below :

```
cellTemplate :  "<div class="progress"> <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ></div> </div>"
```

Now I need to dynamically change the color class for the cellTemplate i.e., `progress-bar-info`. Based column value (complete, incomplete, in progress or fail) I need to have `progress-bar-success, progress-bar-info, progress-bar-warning, progress-bar-danger` in the cellTemplate. How can we achieve it?

I tried the following template but it is giving error:

```
cellTemplate: " <div class=\"progress margin-top-10\"> <div class=\"progress-bar\"   ng-class=\"{progress-bar-success:{{row.entity.status}}==='complete', progress-bar-warning:{{row.entity.status}}==='incomplete', progress-bar-danger:{{row.entity.status}}==='fail'}\"  ng-style=\"{width:'{{row.entity.val}}%'}\"></div> </div>",
```

And the error is as follows :

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 10 of the expression [{progress-bar-success:complete==='complete', progress-bar-warning:complete==='incomplete', progress-bar-danger:complete==='fail'}] starting at [-bar-success:complete==='complete', progress-bar-warning:complete==='incomplete', progress-bar-danger:complete==='fail'}].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-class
**ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression2}"**

In your case something like this

```
<div class="progress-bar"
     ng-class="{'progress-bar-success':row.entity.status==='complete', 'progress-bar-warning':row.entity.status==='incomplete', 'progress-bar-danger':row.entity.status==='fail'}">
</div>
```

Here is the plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ydY6eTFE7PbJ4j8VcM0g?p=preview

Comment: The error you are getting is because of the hyphen in class name . You can wrap them inside ''.

Comment: I have tried that with \'progress-bar-success\' but still it is not working

Comment: Also remove double brackets around row.entity.status

Comment: cellTemplate: " <div class=\"progress margin-top-10\"> <div class=\"progress-bar\"   ng-class=\"{'progress-bar-success':'{{row.entity.code}}'=='complete', 'progress-bar-warning':'{{row.entity.code}}'=='incomplete', 'progress-bar-info':'{{row.entity.code}}'=='inprogress', 'progress-bar-danger':'{{row.entity.code}}'=='fail'}\"  ng-style=\"{width:'{{row.entity.val}}%'}\"></div> </div>", This syntax worked fine. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you controller ;

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('clickCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.dynamicClass = "progress";

});
```

In your view :

```
 cellTemplate :  "<div ng-class="dynamicClass"> <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ></div> </div>"
```

Define css :

```
.progress{
    background-color: orange !important;
}


.done{
    background-color: green!important;
}
```

Comment: He doesnt want to use his own css classes, but for the rest this is right

Comment: In <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ></div>, I want progress-bar-info, to be changed dynamically it could be progress-bar-info or progress-bar-warning, etc based on cell value. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: From this code snippet he can do everything and play around it.

Comment: @smart987 : You need to just give and change your class in dynamicClass variable like $scope.dynamicClass = 'progress-bar-info', then after sometime you can change it like $scope.dynamicClass = 'progress-bar-danger' . This is what all scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should use angulars ngClass directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

In case you do want to use your own styles, just be sure you dont define them as ".ui-grid-cell-contents" It actually works for rowTemplate but not for cellTemplate. I have seen several posts about this and it could save you some trouble.